# How to work kernel irq thread in kernel Linux?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, mmc

I have seen in mmc driver the function `devm_request_threaded_irq` used to launch `sdhci_msm_pwr_irq` like following :

```
ret = devm_request_threaded_irq(&pdev->dev, msm_host->pwr_irq, NULL,
                    sdhci_msm_pwr_irq, IRQF_ONESHOT,
                    dev_name(&pdev->dev), host);
```

But when I call `rmmod` I have not seen an release or stop of this irq thread. Can you explain me how this thread works ?

Answer (score 1):

Removal of the `sdhci-msm` module results in the module's `module_exit` handler function being called, which will call `platform_device_unregister` to unregister itself as a platform device driver. (Most of that is hidden by the macro call `module_platform_driver(sdhci_msm_driver);` in "drivers/mmc/host/sdhci-msm.c".)

When the platform driver is unregistered, all devices that were successfully probed will be removed automatically.  The driver's "remove" handler `sdhci_msm_remove` will be called automatically for each successfully probed device.

So you may be wondering why `sdhci_msm_remove` doesn't free the interrupt allocated by the `devm_request_threaded_irq` call in the "probe" function `sdhci_msm_probe`? The answer is that it doesn't need to because the interrupt was allocated as a "managed device resource" (see below).

`devm_request_threaded_irq` is a "device resource managed" ("devres") wrapper around the `request_threaded_irq` function. Any devres-managed resources get cleaned up automatically when the probed device is being removed. (The clean-up of devres-managed resources happens after the "remove" handler returns.) For devres-managed interrupt resources, the clean-up results in the `free_irq` function being called automatically to free the interrupt.

Comment: when I have run after reboot (and the driver is not loaded) `insmod mmc_host_module.ko` the function `sdhci_msm_pwr_irq()` is not runned directly but when I do `rmmod mmc_host_module` and `insmod mmc_host_module.ko` I got an error because `sdhci_msm_pwr_irq()` directly before executing `init_completion(&msm_host->pwr_irq_completion);` so I got a crash related to `complete(&msm_host->pwr_irq_completion);` called in `sdhci_msm_pwr_irq(...)`, for this reason I ask about free_irq staff when I tried to make a free_irq of msm-host->pwr_irq I got the crash also on rmmod

Comment: @developer If you call `free_irq` directly on a devres-managed interrupt, the interrupt will be freed twice -- once by you and once during the devres clean-up on device removal. So if you need to free the interrupt manually, call `devm_free_irq` instead.

Comment: @IanAbbott, the initial problem is the wrong use of `devm_*_irq()`, i.e. this family of functions mistakenly were converted to support devres and people in most cases took it wrongly. The proper fix is to replace managed call to plain one.

Comment: @0andriy The sdhci code in the vanilla kernel still uses devres. AOSP added all the `pwr_irq_completion` guff which might have introduced some incompatibilities.

Comment: @IanAbbott, yeah, which supports my second part of the first sentence in the previous comment, i.e. *people in most cases took it wrongly*.

Comment: @0andriy,@IanAbbott: my problem consist when I make insmod/rmmod of sdhci-msm drivers twice, the drivers is crashed in second insmod due to the call of `devm_request_threaded_irq()` because `sdhci_msm_pwr_irq()` function is not called directly at first time and it called after `init_completion()`

Comment: @0andriy,@IanAbbott:but the second time of insmod (sdhci_msm_probe()) the function `sdhci_msm_pwr_irq()` is called directly when `devm_request_threaded_irq()` is called so it crashed due the `complete(&msm_host->pwr_irq_completion);` called in `sdhci_msm_pwr_irq()` because it is called before `init_completion()` (of sdhci_msm_probe())

Comment: @developer At least you know why it's crashing, which is something.

Comment: @lanAbbott: for this reason I search how to release this irq thread